# Block multiplication of matrices with a matrix having determinant 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose we have two matrices, $A \in M_{m\times n} (\mathbb {F})$ and $B\in M_{m\times p} (\mathbb {F})$, where $C(B) \subseteq C(A)$. How do you show that there exists a matrix, $P \in M_{n+p\times n+p} (\mathbb {F})$ such that $|P|=1$ and that block multiplication, $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\end{bmatrix}P = \begin {bmatrix} A&0_{m,p}\end{bmatrix}$ is well-defined?

Comment: What are $C(B)$ and $C(A)$?

Comment: $C(B)$ is the column space of $B$ and $C(A)$ is the column space of $A$.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to this. 

Let $P$ be an upper triangular block matrix, such that $P = \begin{bmatrix}C & D\\0 & F\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\end{bmatrix}P = \begin{bmatrix}AC & AD + BF\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A & 0\end{bmatrix}$. 

Then, the matrix block, $C$ must be $I_{n}$. 

Now, determinant, $|P| = 1 = |C||F|$ where it can be concluded that $|D| = 1$. Also, $AD + BF =0$. The only use I have for the clue on the column spaces is that $p\le r$.

Comment: OK, maybe it's not true that $p\le n$.

Comment: @arctictern, $C(B)$ and $C(A)$ are the column spaces of $B$ and $A$ respectively.