# What happens when the column space of a matrix is a subset of a column space of another matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say there are two matrices, $A \in M_{m\times n} (\mathbb {F})$ and $B\in M_{m\times p} (\mathbb {F})$, both in reduced row echelon form, where the column spaces, $C(B) \subseteq C(A)$. Is it true that the columns of $B$ plus additional columns of $A$ span the column space of $A$? Can we also say that since $B$ has $p$ columns and $A$ has $n$ columns, that $p\le n$?

Comment: Not necesarily $p \leq n$. You can have equal column spaces $p > n$, so some columns of $A$ are linear dependent of the others.

Comment: Thanks, @Antioquia3943. I guess, what I meant to say is, if $B$ and $A$ are in reduced row echelon form, then $p \le n$?

Comment: In that case, that is true.

Comment: then obviously true

Comment: Actually, @Antioquia3943,  I'm having trouble thinking of why it's a requirement in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977544/block-multiplication-of-matrices-with-a-matrix-having-determinant-1

Answer (score 0):

take $m,n=3,p=4$
$A=[I_3~0]$ and $B=[e_1~0~0~0]$

Comment: Actually, @user300,  I'm having trouble thinking of why it's a requirement in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977544/block-multiplication-of-matrices-with-a-matrix-having-determinant-1

Answer (score 0):

One can easily see that $p\leq n$ is not true. Even if that is true for a specific choices of matrices $A,B$, now enlarge $B$, by replicating it many times $B'=(B|B |B|\cdots |B)$. The statement $C(B')\subset C(A)$ is still true but if we take $n$ copies of $B$ in $B'$ $p<n$ is definitely not true.

Now to your first part of the question. If you put all olcumns of $A$ as additional columns definitely true; you can prune it by dropping one at a time and checking every time it has the same span as $A$.

Comment: Actually, @P Vanchinathan,  I'm having trouble thinking of why it's a requirement in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977544/block-multiplication-of-matrices-with-a-matrix-having-determinant-1

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of why it's a requirement in this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979776/product-of-two-block-matrices-is-zero?noredirect=1#comment4064411_1979776 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977544/block-multiplication-of-matrices-with-a-matrix-having-determinant-1